# Undefined reference when linking libopencv_gpu.so with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I get an error when trying to compile a single .cpp file

Main.cpp:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/flann/miniflann.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/video.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/ml/ml.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
#include <opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::VideoCapture capture = cv::VideoCapture(argv[1]);
    cv::gpu::GpuMat gpu_frame,gpu_frame_binary;
    cv::Mat frame;
    int threshold_value = 80;
    int threshold_type = 0;
  while (1)
     {
        capture >> frame;
        gpu_frame.upload(frame);
        if (!frame.data)             
            break;

        cv::gpu::threshold(gpu_frame, gpu_frame_binary, threshold_value, 255, threshold_type);
      }
   return 0;
 }
```

OpenCV built with these options:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON -D WITH_OPENEXR=ON -D WITH_UNICAP=ON -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D ENABLE_SSE2=ON -D WITH_CUDA=ON ..
```

Command used to compile:

```
g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o main main.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv` -lopencv_gpu
```

And the error I get:

```
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so: undefined reference to `cv::gpu::convertTo(cv::gpu::GpuMat const&, cv::gpu::GpuMat&, double, double, CUstream_st*)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so: undefined reference to `cv::gpu::setTo(cv::gpu::GpuMat&, cv::Scalar_<double>, cv::gpu::GpuMat const&, CUstream_st*)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so: undefined reference to `cv::gpu::setTo(cv::gpu::GpuMat&, cv::Scalar_<double>, CUstream_st*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I try to compile without the -lopencv_gpu option I get errors like:

```
main.cpp:61: undefined reference to `cv::gpu::threshold(cv::gpu::GpuMat const&, cv::gpu::GpuMat&, double, double, int, cv::gpu::Stream&)'
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

P.S It may be important to note that I first built opencv without cuda, then decided that I wanted to try cuda and built it with cuda option on, and did `sudo make install.` I thought it would overwrite what was previously installed, but maybe something went wrong there?

Running on Fedora 20, with Nvidia card.

Comment: What does `nm /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so | grep convertTo*` returns?

Comment: `                 U _ZN2cv3gpu9convertToERKNS0_6GpuMatERS1_ddP11CUstream_st
                 U _ZNK2cv3gpu6GpuMat9convertToERS1_idd
                 U _ZNK2cv3Mat9convertToERKNS_12_OutputArrayEidd
`

Comment: Please feed that info to `c++filt`to demangle it.

Comment: U
cv::gpu::convertTo(cv::gpu::GpuMat const&, cv::gpu::GpuMat&, double, double, CUstream_st*)
U
cv::gpu::GpuMat::convertTo(cv::gpu::GpuMat&, int, double, double) const
U
cv::Mat::convertTo(cv::_OutputArray const&, int, double, double) const

Comment: Are there other libopencv*.so libraries in /usr/local/lib ? You could chekc them one by one to see where convertTo() is defined (nm shall report something like T cv::gpu::convertTo() )

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem.
To solve it I just deleted `libopencv_gpu.so.2.4` and `libopencv_gpu.so.2.4.10` in `/usr/local/lib/.`